# Phonegap instalation - 'phonegap is not recognized as an internal or'

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I read every article on net how to install phonegap and I try to install million stuff to make it work but again I get this screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx5f6.png

and error: `phonega is not recognized as an internal or external command, oprable program or batch file`

What can be a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Phonegap installation procedures

what are the need for installiation?

1)node js
   download:http://nodejs.org/download/
2)phonegap
   download:http://phonegap.com/install/
3)java jdk
   download:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp
4)ant
   download:http://ant.apache.org/
5)android sdk

### download:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

### PATH SETTING  important

My computer-->Right click-->Properties-->Advanced system settigs-->Environment variables
Edit the Path and give the like this(sample)

### C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\phonegap_project\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;C:\phonegap_project\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;

Not Run JVM  (some times jvm not run)
  Set systems variables
    Click New
     variable Name:_JAVA_OPTIONS
     variable value:-Xmx512M
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------If you facing any issues please let me know i ll help you to clear it.